# Adding a prebuilt APK that requires shared libraries

Tags: android, shared-libraries, apk

The libs are packaged in the apk in the lib directory.

Comment: And what is the question/difficulty?

Comment: Sorry. How do you add a prebuilt APK to a rom that requires shared libraries? I did it the usual way but when I run the app on the device it can't find the libs.

Comment: include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE:= DLNAServer
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(LOCAL_MODULE).apk
LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := APPS
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_MODULE_SUFFIX := $(COMMON_ANDROID_PACKAGE_SUFFIX)
LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := PRESIGNED
include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)

Comment: Installing the APK through ADB works.
Installing the APK by building it with the Android source then flashing it as an in-build app doesn't work.
It can't seem to find the libs that are stored in the lib directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy your shared libraries to system/lib like:

```
PRODUCT_COPY_FILES += \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/libcom_googlecode_android_scripting_Exec.so:system/lib/libcom_googlecode_android_scripting_Exec.so \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/liborg_connectbot_util_EastAsianWidth.so:system/lib/liborg_connectbot_util_EastAsianWidth.so
```

Comment: I'm not making ROM's these days so I can't test this. I'll assume this is correct for anyone else looking for an answer.